# logon denied for sys user when connecting from python to oracle

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, cx-oracle

I'm facing logon denied error when connecting to Oracle 11g using python 3.4. with oracle client library version 5.1.3. I have observed this issue only with user "sys as sysdba", but not with other user. I'm able to connect to Oracle with "sys as sysdba" from other DB clients. I have used below to code to connect.

```
dns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('xxxxxx','1521','db')
con = cx_Oracle.connect('sys as sysdba', 'xxxxx', dns)
```

Please advice, what I'm doing wrong.

thanks.

Comment: I would be very surprised if you actually have a good reason for wanting to connect to the `sys` user programmatically.  There should be no need for that.

Comment: @sstan There is no use case :), actually I'm learning to connect to DB using Python, just want to know what is the reason behind the above problem

Comment: `sys` is special.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the mode parameter

```
dns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('xxxxxx','1521','db')
con = cx_Oracle.connect('sys', 'sysPassword', dns, cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
```

or

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect('sys/sysPassword@localhost:1521/db', mode = cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
```

cx_Oracle.connect([user, password, dsn, mode, handle, pool, threaded, twophase, events, cclass, purity, newpassword])

http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/module.html?highlight=connect#cx_Oracle.connect

Comment: Thanks for providing the doc